# Confusion related to regular expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have this confusion related to regular expression. If there are *two sets* `A` and `B` then

is `(AB)* = A*B*`?

Comment: By "sets", do you mean character classes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Might be better suited at [cs.se]

Answer (score 6):

### IN CONTEXT OF REGULAR EXPRESSION:  is (AB)* = A*B*?

```
 No, (AB)* is not equals to A*B*
```

`(AB)* means ABABABABAB......AB`  A sequence of AB  (any number of time).
   `A*B* means AAAA.....BBB......` Any number of A's followed by any number of B's. And A can't appear after B's.

Intersection - Both includes `{ NULL string, AB }` only

---

**Example:**

Suppose:   `A = xy` , and    `B = z`

```
  (AB)* = xyzxyz.....xyz  
  A*B*  =  xyxyxyxy....zzzz....z
```

**Intersection** - Both includes `{ NULL string, xyz}` only.

---

**Example:**

Suppose -

```
  A = {a, b},  
  B = {c, d}
```

Then,

```
(AB)* =  ((a + b)(c + d))* , Its language  
L =  { ac, ab, acbd, acac, .....}
```

**NOTE:** All string in this language are of even length!

And

```
A*B*  =   (a + b)* (c + d)* , Its language     
  L = { a, b, c, d, ac, ad, bc, bd, acbd, addb,.........}
```

**NOTE:** Also contains odd length strings.

Comment: I understand your `A = ab B = c` example, but it's confusing. I suggest using `A = xy B = z` for clarity.

Comment: changed a,b,c with x,y,z for your continence. Standard is small letter use to denote language symbols and Capital for SET

Comment: Also, one should not use z, x, y, w ... (small alphabetic from last) standard says its for String of language.

Comment: The problem is just that `ab` is confusing when you have `A` and `B`. `A = a B = bc` would have worked also. Anyway, one of your upvotes is from me.

Comment: Thanks @JustinMorgan! I just like to share my knowledge :) . Thanks And Happy Diwali!

Answer (score 1):

```
(AB)* = A*B*  ?
```

No. The first is the language

```
 {void, ab, abab, ababab, ...}
```

the second is the language

```
{void, a, b, aa, ab, bb, aaa, ...}
```

Comment: I don't agree with `ba` for the second example.