# How to convert an NFA to the corresponding Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, computation-theory, nfa

I am studying for tomorrows exam and I have checked many tutorials telling how to convert NFA to Regex but I can't seem to confirm my answers. Following the tutorials, I solved that NFA

[image]

My solution was:

> **a*ba***

Am I correct?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm you learned in class. If I were the TA, I'd only accept the regular expression obtained from executing the algorithm correctly... which might be different, contain + and parentheses, etc.

Comment: The algorithm I learned in class covered converting the automata to GNFA then reducing by eliminating one state at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to convert NFA to Regular Expression?

Your answer `a*ba*` is Correct. I can drive your answer from `NFA` in given image as follows:

- There is a self loop on start state q<sub>0</sub> with label `a`. So there can be any number of `a`s are possible at initial (prefix) including null `^` in RE. So Regular Expression(RE) start with `a*`.
- You need only one `b` to reach to final state. Actually for an accepting string; there must be at-least one `b` in string of `a` and `b`. So RE `a*b` to reach to either q<sub>1</sub> or q<sub>2</sub>. Both are *final states*.
- Once you reach to a final state (q<sub>1</sub> or q<sub>2</sub>). No other `b` is possible in string (there is no outgoing edge for `b` from q<sub>1</sub> and q<sub>2</sub>).
- Only symbol is `a` can be possible at q<sub>1</sub> and q<sub>2</sub>. Also for, `a` at q<sub>1</sub> or at q<sub>2</sub> move switch between q<sub>1</sub> , q<sub>2</sub> and both are final.  So after symbol `b` any number of `a`s can be in suffix. (So string ends with `a*` ).

And RE is `a*ba*`.

Also, its **DFA** is as follows:

```
 DFA: 
======

    a-          a-  
    ||          ||
    ▼|          ▼|
--►(q0)---b---►((q1))      

    a*    b      a*    :RE  
                       ====
```

- Any number of `a`s at `q0` that is:   `a*`
- once you get `b` you can switch to final state `q1`:  `b`
- at final state any number of `a` is possible:  `a*`

And its a Minimized DFA!

Here is some more interesting answer by me on `FAs` and `REs`, I believe will be useful to you:

1. [HOW TO WRITE REGULAR EXPRESSION FOR A DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717)
2. [RE TO DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122755/what-will-be-the-dfa-for-the-regular-expression-00101011?answertab=votes#tab-top)
3. [Regular Expression to DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770814/drawing-minmal-dfa-for-the-given-regular-expression/14024179#14024179)
4. [Constructing an equivalent Regular Grammar from a Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars/13945932#13945932)
5. [How to Eliminate Left recursion in Context-Free-Grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033250/left-recursion-elimination/14041093#14041093)
6. [Is a* the same as (a*)*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779645/is-a-the-same-as-a/13779675#13779675)
7. [IN CONTEXT OF REGULAR EXPRESSION:  is `(AB)* = A*B*?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355710/confusion-related-to-regular-expression/13355754#13355754)

Answer (score 1):

That answer is correct, in that both of the following are true:

- Any string matching the regular expression causes the NFA to end in an accepting state (double circled state)
- Any string causing the NFA to end in an accepting state also matches the regular expression

However, I can't check your work because you haven't posted any.